# How to send img to server with JQuery and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

How to send img to server with JQuery and Flask, I'm gonna send img to flask server and i don'r know how to do it can you help me

JQuery:

```
$file_upload.on('change', function () {
            console.log($('#avatar_img_change')[0].files[0]);
            $.getJSON('/change_avatar/', {
                avatar: $('#avatar_img_change')[0].files[0]
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data.error);
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative;" id="av-div">
                {% if current_user.avatar_name != None%}
                    <img src="../static/images/users/{{current_user.generated_id}}/{{current_user.avatar_name}}" alt="avatar" class="user-block__avatar">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="../static/images/dev/unknownperson.png" alt="avatar" class="user-block__avatar">
                {% endif %}
                <label for="avatar_img_change" class="user-block__avatar-change font-color_grey">Change</label>
                <input type="file" id="avatar_img_change" class="user-block__avatar-input">
            </div>
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Which part do you have a problem with? It seems like you already got some code together so you could specify your question further than "I don't know how". Could you share your Flask code? If you don't know how to start with the flask code, you can take a look at the section on [file uploads](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#file-uploads) in the quickstart section and then take it from there.

Comment: Expanding on what @oschlueter said, the url route that the image is going to is quite important too, so please share it with us.